# Is there a way to find what processes are in nice CPU top list?

Tags: unix, top, android

I have a top output that shows a high amount in `nic` CPU percentage.
[image: top output]

Is there a way to see what those processes are? And is it possible to do it from top?

Comment: That's busybox top, which indicates: (1) you're only going to get minimal information, (2) you're on Android, and (3) this doesn't appear to be on topic here.

Comment: The concern is still one of cpu usage tracking and management on a unix platform. In that sense, is it relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest displaying all processes with `ps` and simply sort by niceness, for example:

```
ps ax -o pid,ni,cmd | sort -k 2
```

Comment: how does that output add up to the nice number at the top? i.e. the number at the first line of my screenshot. can we see how they aggregate to a cpu consumed figure?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a really nice tool called htop.

Not sure which package manager you're working with but htop can be downloaded from the general ones.

When you run htop there's a menu list in the bottom screen, if you press 'F6' it will show you different display options which one of them is to sort by NICE.

Example:
[image: htop sorting options]

**Edit:**
htop also allows you to interactively increase or decrease nice value of processes.

Comment: how does that output add up to the nice number at the top? i.e. the number at the first line of my screenshot. can we see how they aggregate to a cpu consumed figure?

Comment: Since -11 is the lowest nice value at the moment of the screen shot then I guess that this is what it shows, the process with the highest priority. For more information check https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-htop/  and check the information I added to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, just need to understood how that becomes a cpu consumed figure. The first line in my top output is a breakdown of cpu consumption. It seems like some nice'd processes are consuming cpu.